# 配列に対して，ある値以上の場合は配列の要素から取り除きたい

Tags: ruby

Ruby勉強中の者です．

配列に対して，ある値（実数）以上の場合は配列の要素から取り除きたいです．
簡潔に記述したいのですが，どのようにしたら良いでしょうか

ご教授よろしくお願いします
以下では整数を例としています

```
threshold = 35
arr = [1, 5, 39, 43, 22, 51]
arr_s = arr.sort  # 昇順にソート
# 以降で，threshold 以上の場合配列から取り除く
# => [1, 5, 22]
```

Comment: [instance method Enumerable#reject (Ruby 2.6.0)](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Enumerable/i/reject.html) を使う場合: `arr.reject {|n| n >= threshold}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr_s.reject { |x| x >= threshold }
```

または

```
arr_s.take_while { |x| x < threshold }
```

Answer (score 2):

プログラムの都合上、ソート済みのものについて高速に処理したいということであれば、  
二分探索のメソッドがあるので、それで閾値のindexを取得すれば以下のように記述できます。

```
index = arr_s.bsearch_index { |x| x >= threshold }
arr_s.slice(0, index || arr_s.size)
```

`reject` などを使えば、ソート済みの配列でなくても要素の選別ができます。

FYI: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Array/i/bsearch.html

Answer (score 1):

NArrayなら

```rb
require 'numo/narray'

arr = Numo::Int32[1, 5, 39, 43, 22, 51]
arr[arr < 35]

# => Numo::Int32(view)#shape=[3]
# [1, 5, 22]
```

ですね。